# Why are my 'views' pages no longer displaying?

Tags: views

The two pages on my Drupal site that are created by the 'views' module are not displaying. They have displayed with no problem for over a year; this problem started today, as far as I can tell.

/directory  /allmembers  are displaying as completely blank (white) pages.  They are both 'views' modules.

When I go to /admin ,  I see this:
One or more problems were detected with your Drupal installation. Check the status report for more information.

Following the Status Report link to here  /admin/reports/status 
I see a warning (yellow triangle) for Drupal core update status;  a red X for MS Core and Messaging PHP Mailer; and also a red X with the Unicode Library error:
  Unicode library Error Multibyte string input conversion in PHP is active and must be disabled. Check the php.ini mbstring.http_inputsetting. Please refer to the PHP mbstring documentation for more information.
(MS Core and Messaging PHP Mailer both appear to be items that we do not use on our site.)

I have checked in with my hosting provider; they restored an old version, but there is still the same issue.

I don't know enough about PHP to understand the Unicode error message, nor do I know why that would have changed at all in the past 24 hours.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: For errors you should check the "watchdog". Add the relevant reports to the post.

Comment: I've spent time looking up "watchdog," so I now have an idea what you are talking about, but I don't know how to check the watchdog of a particular Drupal site. I don't have access to the SQL (or don't know what to do with it, if I did have access).

Comment: Can you add the log messages that correlate with opening the /directory and/or /allmembers pages

Comment: Well. Finally found this: http://meditationandpsychotherapy.org/admin/reports/dblog (Thanks for the push.)
Redefining already defined constructor for class MsAdjustment in /home6/meditav4/public_html/sites/all/modules/ms_core/ms_core.classes.php on line 470.  {repeated with many different lines}

Comment: Also this:  Only variables should be passed by reference in /home6/meditav4/public_html/sites/all/modules/captcha/captcha.inc on line 61.

And this, which specifically mentions views: Declaration of views_handler_sort::query() should be compatible with views_handler::query($group_by = false) in /home6/meditav4/public_html/sites/all/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_sort.inc on line 165.

Comment: It seems that you're site has many errors. I suggest the following. Mark the last watchdog entry, enter the view page, see what other logs are added.

Comment: Just did this; there are 3.5 pages of new logs. (Same as the three posted above - Redefining, Only variables, and Declaration of views).
I appreciate your help, but don't want to put something too big on your plate.

Comment: See if some of these errors occur on there pages. That way you can filter out the trouble.